# Sci-fi/fantasy anthology book series from early 90s with titles 'Unicorns', 'Dragons', 'Fairies' etc

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Does anyone know a series of books from the early 90s, short story anthologies from the sci-fi/fantasy genre, each book focusing on a particular topic reflected in the title. 'Unicorns' 'Dragons' 'Fairies' 'Dwarfs' and so on for about 20 books.

Comment: I had a book called "A Cavalcade of Dragons," and I think there were more, but I have not idea when they were published.  There might have been a "Cavalcade of Goblins?"

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like it could be an anthology series from Jack Dann & Gardner Dozois. Titles included *Unicorns!*, *Magicats!*, *Mermaids!*, *and Dragons!*.

ISFDB calls it ["The Exclamatory Series"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?8439) (for obvious reasons). Wikipeda says it was called the "Magic Tales Anthology Series" until the focus changed from fantasy to SF, so they now call it the ["Jack Dann and Gardner Dozois Ace anthology series"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Dann_and_Gardner_Dozois_Ace_anthology_series).

The first book in the series was *Aliens!* in 1980. The last was either *Clones!* in 1998 (per ISFDB) or *Dangerous Games* in 2007 (per Wikipedia).

Answer (score 4):

There was also a series edited by Isaac Asimov, [Magical Worlds of Fantasy](http://www.goodreads.com/series/71332-isaac-asimov-s-magical-worlds-of-fantasy), which started in 1981 and ran to 11 books, the last in 1989. The themed anthologies were Wizards, Witches, Cosmic Knights, Spells, Giants, Mythical Beasts, Magical Wishes, Devils, Atlantis, Ghosts and Curses.